# Total SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need a query that totals with sum others columns

```
User     sales    amount    date
--------------------------------------
danny    car      10.000    25/02/2016
danny    moto      5.000    26/02/2016
danny    car      10.000    25/03/2016
danny    moto      5.000    26/03/2016
danny    moto      5.000    26/03/2016
danny    car      10.000    25/04/2016
danny    moto      5.000    26/04/2016
danny    car      10.000    25/05/2016
danny    moto      5.000    26/05/2016
```

Result between dates filter by user and date should by:

between 01/03/2016 and 31/03/2016

```
User   Total   moto    car     
------------------------------
danny  15.000  2        1
```

What query do I need?

Comment: Show us **your effort so far** first! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? We'll **help** - but we won't just **write the whole code** for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Pivot`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT User,sales,amount,datename(month, date)
   FROM YoyrTable   
)A
PIVOT
(
   SUM(amount)
   FOR sales in ([car],[moto])
)B
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('danny', 'car', 10.000, '2016-02-15'),
('danny', 'moto', 5.000, '2016-02-26'),
('danny', 'car', 10.000, '2016-03-25'),
('danny', 'moto', 5.000, '2016-03-26'),
('danny', 'moto', 5.000, '2016-03-26'),
('danny', 'car', 10.000, '2016-04-25'),
('danny', 'moto', 5.000, '2016-04-26'),
('danny', 'car',  10.000, '2016-05-25'),
('danny', 'moto', 5.000, '2016-05-26')
) as t([User], sales, amount, [date])
)

SELECT  [user],
        SUM(amount) as Total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sales = 'moto' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as moto,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sales = 'car' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as car,
        DATENAME(Month,[date]) as [date]
FROM cte
GROUP BY [user], DATENAME(Month,[date]),DATEPART(Month,[date]), DATEPART(Year,[date])
ORDER BY DATEPART(Month,[date]), DATEPART(Year,[date])
```

Output:

```
user    Total   moto    car date
danny   15.000  1       1   February
danny   20.000  2       1   March
danny   15.000  1       1   April
danny   15.000  1       1   May
```

In query put your table name instead `cte`

Answer (score 1):

what your actual `PIVOT` should look like..

```
SELECT  [User],
        Total,
        [moto],
        [car],
        [date] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  [User],
            sales,
            DATENAME(MONTH,date) [date],
            SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [User], DATENAME(MONTH,date)) [Total]
    FROM    cte
) T
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(sales)
    FOR sales IN ([car], [moto])
) p
```

the answer by @gofr1 should perform better though.